# HTTP Callout in a flow to make a Marketing Cloud callout

Tags: visual-workflow, callout, http, named, credentials

Hello,

I would like to call a Marketing Cloud API from a flow in Salesforce.

I have 2 options, first is to use an invocable apex method (tested and it works fine).
Second option is to use a HTTP Callout Action, it is my choice because no code (so better I think).

I watched some [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDkFGVdY95c&ab_channel=SFDCGirl) but it was not about Marketing Cloud.

To make a Marketing Cloud callout, we need first to get a Bearer Token from a first call, then we can call the Marketing Cloud API by passing the bearer token in the header, it means we need 2 API calls to call the Marketing Cloud API.

I created the 2 named credentials (the second is the "External Credential" of the first), add the second named credential to a permission set and I assigned the permission set to myself.

I added the crendentials (client_od, client_secrent and grant_type) to the second named credential.
The first named credential has an URL but not the second (the one to get the bearer token).

Then I created the HTTP Callout Action in the flow and I use the first named credentials as  named credential in the action flow.

But at the end, I get the "Not authorized" error message with the 401 code.

Because we have 2 callouts to do, is HTTP Callout compatible with HTTP Callout in Salesforce flow?
Or is it because we don't use exactly the same URL to get the bearer token and to call the Marketing Cloud API?

To get the bearer token: `https://***.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token`

To call the Marketing Cloud API: `https://***.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events`

Thanks